# Payment with Saferpay, whats the correct Success url?

Tags: php, mysql, payment, shopping-cart

In my online shop, I'm using Saferpay as a Payment Gateway.
When the customer clicks the "Pay" button, his order will be stored in my MySQL table called `orders`, and the customer will be directly forwarded to the payment page.

I set the ReturnUrls like this:

Fail: to the "fail.php", which has a MySQLl query that will delete the order from the database.

Success: to the "success.php", which has a MySQL query that will change the value of a column (`Order_Status`) in the table from 0 to 1 and that will make me send him the order.

The problem is :
if the customer clicked the "Pay" button (his order is stored in the DB with the value 0 in the `Order_Status` column), and if visited the success.php page, then the query on that page will run and set his order `Order_Status` to 1, and that will make the order appear as its paid for me.

I'm satisfied with the fail.php page, but what's the best way to fix the success.php page so the query inside it will not run unless the customer has completed the payment?

I've tried to store the RedirectUrl I get from Saferpay (this is the link that the customer will be directed to start the payment process) to compare it with the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and run the query if `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == $RedirectUrl`, but it didn't work because the payment starts with the `$RedirectUrl` but the process makes it go through other unique pages before it's directed to the success.php page.

Here is the success.php :

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
include 'init.php';

$orderId = $_SESSION['OrderId'];
$carts = $_SESSION['carts'];
$RedirectUrl = $_SESSION['RedirectUrl'];
if(isset($orderId) && is_numeric($orderId)){

      // changing the Order_Status to 1
      $stmtSucess =$con->prepare("UPDATE orders SET Order_Status = 1 WHERE Order_ID = ?");
      $stmtSucess->execute(array($orderId));
      
        
      // changing the status of the Cart Products from 0 to 1 (ordered)
      $theOrders1 = explode('::', $carts);
      foreach($theOrders1 as $order1){
      $stmt1=$con->prepare("UPDATE carts SET Cart_Status = 1 WHERE Cart_ID = ?");
      $stmt1->execute(array($order1));
      }

      if($stmtSucess){
        echo lang('THANK_YOU');
      }

      header('location:profile.php#profile-orders?lang='.$sessionLang);
      exit();

}else{
  header('location:index.php?lang='.$sessionLang);
  exit();
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: There should be something built into safepay to help handle this. You need a 2 way verification system. What is the SDK you are using?

Comment: no SDK , but a JSON API

Answer (score 0):

Got it, I had to send a request to Saferpay Assert Page with the payment unique information. And I'll get a response in a JSON Object with the result